# 301 redirections when migrating from Wordpress to Ghost

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ghost-blog

I want to migrate my WP blog to ghost, the permalinks have the same slug (`/blogWP.com/title-article` and `blogGhost.com/title-article`) but I still have pages such as blog.com/category for instance to redirect.

Is there any way to make 301 redirections in Ghost as I would do in a .htaccess file ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to redirect through ghost itself directly, but you need to alter the core. Though I'm not sure it's the perfect or proper way.

open `core/server/errorHandling.js`

find this line:

```
error404: function (req, res, next) {
```

Add below:

```
res.status(301); 
res.set({'Location': 'http://your-new-wordpress-blog-url'+req.url});
res.send('301','Not found');
```

This way, Instead of showind 404s, I redirect to my wordpress' new domain (`http://your-new-wordpress-blog-url` in the example)

This way, `www.ghost.url/not-a-valid-page` will redirect to `http://your-new-wordpress-blog-url/not-a-valid-page` instead of showing the Ghost's 404 page.

p.s: This redirects, but I'm not 100% sure the headers are correct, I'd appreciate if someone else would clarify.

Comment: Thanks Arda, seems to be working although I wish there was a proper way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there is currently no way to do redirects with Ghost.

The best way to do redirects is to use a proxy server (recommended) and do the redirects there. For Apache you could use `.htaccess` files and nginx offers [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sebgie, I guess Ghost is not that mature yet :/

Comment: @user1720723 No, there is a way, please see my answer.

Comment: Yes there is a way by rewriting Ghost, but it is currently not supported to do 301 redirects out of the box.It depends on your experience and willingness to apply the patch for every future release.

Answer (score 0):

My ghost blog is a subdirectory `/blog/` runing with NGINX.
I needed to redirect old wordpress urls **/blog/category/post-title** to **/blog/post-title**

Except for `/blog/ghost/..`, `/blog/tag/..`, `/blog/author/..`, `/blog/post-title/amp/`.

**So I came with that rewrite rule :**
`rewrite ^/blog/(?:(?!ghost|tag|author).).*/(?:(?!amp))(.+)$ /blog/$1 permanent;`